# What would a backdoor in symmetric key cipher look like?

Tags: symmetric

Pretty much what the title says. DES was suspected of having one, but I couldn't imagine what it could possibly look like if only the NSA knew how to use it. Dual_EC_DRBG's backdoor is asymmetric, but it's not a cipher. Could one have a kletographic symmetric key cipher?

Comment: You will probably find [this Schneier](http://eprint.iacr.org/2015/097.pdf) paper interesting. Intentional side-channels are probably the most robust to implement (without getting caught) if you are not a block-cipher cryptanalysis guru.

Comment: This is already covered by https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1935/351 and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/675/351 (both of which you could have found by searching in the [tag:backdoors] tag).

Answer (score 2):

As usual, inserting a backdoor in a symmetric cipher becomes a lot easier if you have knowledge your adversaries lack.

DES is a pretty good (counter)example of how a backdoor could be introduced in a symmetric cipher.

Back in 1974, IBM and the NSA both knew about [differential cryptanalysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_cryptanalysis), but they did not publish their findings. Some 16 years later, differential cryptanalysis was rediscovered and published by Biham and Shamir. As they found out, DES's S-boxes – which are precisely the part of DES prople suspected to contain a backdoor – were surprisingly resistent to differential cryptanalysis.

As it turned out, the S-boxes were designed to to repel this type of attack. In theory, since the NSA knew about differential cryptanalysis but the general public didn't, they could have chosen S-boxes that were exceptionally vulnerable to it. That would have been a backdoor.

Another example would be the use of apparent [trapdoor functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapdoor_function) with a known inverse.

To see how this could be exploited, suppose nobody knew about RSA. Define $R(X)$ as the RSA encryption of $X$ with a certain public key and design a cipher that generates the stream $$R(1\times K) || R(2\times K) || R(3\times K) || \cdots$$ where $K$ is the secret key for your stream cipher.

If you know the associated private key, you can easily compute $R^{-1}$. Now, if you know enough plain- and ciphertext to figure out part of the stream – let's say $R(1\times K)$ – all you have to do is apply $R^{-1}$ to figure out $K$.

Nobody will be able detect the vulnerability without essentially discovering RSA.

Comment: For a stream cipher?

Comment: Yes, the cipher derived from the RSA algorithm would be a stream cipher. (Not sure if that was your question.)